# Question about Conway's functional analysis chapter 2, exercise 1

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $\mathscr{H}$ be a Hilbert space and suppose $f$ and $g$ are linearly independent vectors in $\mathscr{H}$ with $\|f\|=\|g\|=1$. Show that $\|tf + (1-t)g\| < 1$ for all $0 < t < 1$. What does this say about $\{h \in \mathscr{H} \colon \|h\| \leq 1\}$.

I have proven the statement, but I am unsure about what there is to say about the subset $\{h \in \mathscr{H} \colon \|h\| \leq 1 \}$. Clearly it is a convex subset of $\mathscr{H}$, but what else can we say about it that is of interest?

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think that's what you're supposed to say: it's a convex subset.

Comment: I believe convexity is the property Conway was going for. Convexity of sets of Hilbert spaces is a very nice property that allows you to do things like orthogonal projection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not only convex, but strictly convex! (this is an important property in the theory of normed vector spaces)

Comment: I see thank you!

Comment: It is not only strictly convex, but uniformly convex!

Comment: It is weird though, Conway has only introduced convexity so far. So the reader should not be assumed to know about uniformly convex or the like.